# OnsenUIでツールバーやタブバーを固定するには

Tags: onsen-ui

ツールバーやタブバーを利用した場合、ブラウザによっては上下にスクロールできてしまいます。
HTMLやCSSの記述を工夫することで、位置を完全に固定する方法はあるでしょうか。

OnsenUIの例（iPhoneのSafariで表示すると画面全体がスクロール対象となる）
http://s.codepen.io/onsen/fullembedgrid/pGuDL

SenchTouchの例（iPhoneのSafariで表示しても中央のコンテンツ領域のみがスクロール対象となる）
http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.4.1/examples/kitchensink/#demo/bottom-tabs

Answer (score 1):

画面全体の上下スクロールに関してはcomfig.xml内にある

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true">
```

のvalueをfalseにすることでバウンドしないようにできます。
記述がない場合は、

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false">
```

を追加すればよいです。